# How to fix error Program type already present: android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel

Tags: android

I use the com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar in my project but when I run the program I get an error and emulator doesn't run. How can I fix it?

error:

```
Program type already present: android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel
Message{kind=ERROR, text=Program type already present: android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel, sources=[Unknown source file], tool name=Optional.of(D8)}
```

Build.gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "ir.infoprocoers.bottomappbar"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0-alpha1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0-alpha1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```